# create API by using generic.ListAPI take too much time

Tags: django, api

I am creating API in django by using generic.ListAPI when i hit this API it take too much time approx. 5 min. Below is my code what mistake i did can anybody help me

```py
class KeyMarket(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = UserAddress.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserAddressSerializer

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        b = []
        add = []
        filter_data=UserAddress.objects.filter(address_type='1')
        serializer = self.get_serializer(filter_data, many=True)
        b.append(serializer.data)

        for i in range(len(serializer.data)):
            c = serializer.data[i]
            add.append(c['address'])

        re = set(add)
        return Response(re)
```

Comment: Add your models, serializers, and what you want to get from this endpoint!

Comment: You are not using `queryset = UserAddress.objects.all()` , just use a normal viewsets.ViewSet instead, and use list comprehension in this `for i in range(len(serializer.data))` loop

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ListApiView** and do this,

```
class ShowArticles(ListAPIView):
    """
    This API will return the list of all Articles.
    """
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated,]
    serializer_class = ShowArticleSerializer
    queryset = Article.objects.all()
```